# Python Pandas : Unable to return dictionary in two different columns based on groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe which is like below,

```
df1:
  mac            gw_mac         building  rssi type    payload
0 0010403bf0db   b827eb36fb0b   main      -45  iBeacon e2c56db5dffb48d2b060d0f5a71096e0
1 0010403bf0db   d827fc36gc0c   main      -67  other   02010612ff590080bc2c01001d0b3a00000005000000 
2 bf0db0010403   b827eb36fb0b   main      -71  iBeacon e2c56db5dffb48d2b060d0f5a71096e0  
3 bf0db0010403   d827fc36gc0c   main      -59  other   02010612ff590080bc2c01001d0b3a00000005000000
```

Based on the group of "mac" & "building", the column values of "gw_mac" and "rssi" has to be framed as dictionary in the name of "gw_mac_rssi" column.

Similarly, Based on the same grouping condition which is mentioned above, the column values of "payload" and "type" has to be framed as dictionary in the name of "payload_type" and the resultant dataframe is suppose to be,

```
df2:
  mac             building    gw_mac_rssi                              payload_type
0 0010403bf0db    main        {'b827eb36fb0b':-45,'d827fc36gc0c':-67} {'e2c56db5dffb48d2b060d0f5a71096e0':'iBeacon','02010612ff590080bc2c01001d0b3a00000005000000':'other'}
1 bf0db0010403    main        {'b827eb36fb0b':-71,'d827fc36gc0c':-59} {'e2c56db5dffb48d2b060d0f5a71096e0':'iBeacon','02010612ff590080bc2c01001d0b3a00000005000000':'other'}
```

I have tried with

```
df.groupby(['mac',  'building']) \
    .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('edge_mac_gw_mac_rssi')['rssi'].to_dict()).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('type')['payload'].to_dict()).reset_index(name=["gw_mac_rssi","payload_type"])
```

Can I anyone please help me out in framing two different dictionaries based on same grouping condition with multiple column values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's see how to add one column of dictionary from groupby object:

```
df.groupby(['mac','building']).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['gw_mac'],x['rssi'])))
```

Then for two columns simultaneously generated, we need to return `pandas.Series` from the lambda function, then it becomes:

```py
df.groupby(['mac','building']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([dict(zip(x['gw_mac'],x['rssi'])),
        dict(zip(x['payload'],x['type']))],index=['gw_mac_rssi','payload_type']))
```

Should generate the desired result, I didn't play with your input though, used simple input and worked.